# Lasso optimization with function of trace(XAXB)-log det X

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

My optimization problem is:
$$
\underset{X=X^T}{\text{argmin}}\;\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(XAXB) - \log \det(X) + \lambda \|X\|_{1}
$$
Here, $X\in{\bf R}^{p \times p}$, $A$ and $B$ are all $p$-dimensional symmetric positive definite matrices.
$\|X\|_{1}=\sum_{i,j} {|X_{ij}|}$

Can anyone know how to solve this optimization problem?

I know that [glasso](https://academic.oup.com/biostatistics/article/9/3/432/224260) can solve
$$
\text{argmin}\;\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(X) - \log \det(X) + \lambda \|X\|_{1}
$$
and [D-trace](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/101/1/103/2366063) can solve
$$
\text{argmin}\;\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(X^2\Sigma) - \text{tr}(X) + \lambda\|X\|_{1}
$$

Comment: could you clarify is $\|\cdot\|_1$ the operator norm or the element-wise norm?

Comment: Thanks, $\|X\|_{1}=\sum_{i,j} { |X_{ij}| }$

Comment: What do you mean by solve? Do you want to create an optimization routine yourself or you just care about the solution? In that case you can use any convex solver

Comment: It is acceptable to create a new routine or follow any existed routine.